How do I distribute a DriverKit Extension to multiple third parties on iOS?
We're developing a framework that needs to talk to a camera on iOS. We've written a Driverkit Extension to enable this but we're having trouble working out how to distribute this to third parties.
We have to specify the application's bundle ID in the driverkit extensions's bundle ID to successfully build an application that includes the driverkit extension. But, as far as we can tell, that means if multiple consumers want to bundle this into their app, they each need their own specially built driverkit extension.
We'd like to avoid creating a separate app that hosts the driverkit extension for other apps/user-clients to connect to. Because then the end user would need to download and run our hosting app each time they want to run the client app.
Am I missing something? Or is it expected that we should have to build a new driverkit extension with a different bundle ID for every app that every third party wants to develop?

You probably need to move your proprietary code into a framework that you distribute as a binary and provide a source-code driver kit extension that uses the framework. Then the consumer can build and sign the driver kit extension, providing the necessary bundle id.

I'm not 100% sure I understand your use case. A few questions: (1) Do third party apps that should use your dext need to specify custom match dictionaries? In other words, is this a driver for an OEM device which is then rebranded with different USB/PCI vendor/product IDs? (2) Is it acceptable for the user to need to install your app to install the dext, and then use that dext from third party apps? Or are you looking for a 1-app solution? (3) Presumably you're defining an IOUserClient API in your dext which 3rd party apps then implement either directly or via a library you supply them?

@Paulw11, thanks for the response. This seems like it might be a solution we could go with. I think our main concern would be we're shifting all of the complexity of signing and building onto the consumer. Perhaps not too tricky, but it'd be nice to avoid if possible. We'd prefer a solution where we could just give each third party the same framework and driverkit extension, and our framework could use the camera via the driverkit extension.

@pmdj, thanks for responding hopefully I can clarify my use case -

The client shouldn't need to specify custom match dictionaries. The camera will have a consistent VID and PID.
The latter, we're looking for a 1-app solution if it's possible. The main reason being we want the experience to be as simple as possible for the end user, so when our consumer publishes their app on the app store - it should 'just work'.
Exactly, we'd like third parties to just use our framework that uses our dext. Ideally they wouldn't have to worry about the dext beyond bundling it in their app.


So ideally, you want to create a signed binary dext which your customers can then embed in their own apps. I think this might actually work; I can easily try this with development or ad hoc signed dext/apps; if it does that still doesn't guarantee that Apple allows it on the App Store though. It might be worth querying this with Apple DTS before spending much effort on a specific architecture.

There is an entitlement that allows for connections from apps with a different bundle id:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_driverkit_allow-third-party-userclients
Edit:
This one is maybe also interesting. It is an entitlement that let's other vendors distribute your extension.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_system-extension_redistributable

Thanks for your response tuple_cat - unfortunately I don't think this isn't quite what I'm looking for. This is an entitlement that would allow other apps to connect to our app that hosts the driverkit extension. As far as I can tell, that would mean the end-user would need to install and run our app alongside the actual app.
If there was a way for an app deployed via the app-store to specify the dependency on our app, and then the lifetime of our app to be dependent on that app. This would be fine, but I don't think it's currently possible.

Sorry, I posted the wrong entitlement. I've edited the answer to include the entitlement that I was thinking of.

No worries! That new one looks like it could be what we want - although based on the documentation it looks like it's macOS only.
